# Cortar un string en un determinado caracter sin perderlo en Java

Tags: java

Pretendo elaborar un método que me permita cortar un string en un array de fragmentos a partir de una determinada palabra o conjuntos de palabras. He intentado usar `split()` de java.String, pero este método corta y **elimina** el conjunto de caracteres que le has indicado como punto de corte.

¿Existe algún método que realice el corte pero sin perder el punto de corte, o alguna forma de solventar este problema?

Pongo un ejemplo. Tengo:

```
query = "SELECT users FROM call ORDER BY call.employee_id ASC, call.start_time ASC";
```

Y yo quiero que, tras el corte, quede así:

```
query[0] = "SELECT users ";
query[1] = "FROM call ORDER BY call.employee_id ASC, call.start_time ASC";
```

Es decir, no tengo un delimitador concreto del que pueda prescindir, por lo que si indico que el punto de corte sea, en el ejemplo, "FROM", el resultado es

```
query[0] = "SELECT users ";
query[1] = " call ORDER BY call.employee_id ASC, call.start_time ASC";
```

Comment: probaste con subString()? Devuelve un fragmento de una cadena sin modificarla. Creo que se puede hacer con expresiones regulares tambien.

Comment: El problema de subString, hasta donde sé, es que el criterio de corte es una determinada posición en el string, indicada con un entero. Sin embargo, la idea es que el string se corte cuando aparezca una determinada palabra, independientemente de en qué posición se encuentre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto debería funcionar:

```js
const editor = 'conseparoestoseparofunciona'
console.log(editor.split(/(separo)/));
```

1. Remplazas todas las "d" por otras ",d"
2. Split con la ","

```js
var string = "abcdeabcde";
var newstringreplaced = string.replace(/d/gi, ",d");
var newstring = newstringreplaced.split(",");
console.log(newstring);
```

Y para tu ejemplo sería algo tal que así.

```js
var string = "SELECT users FROM call ORDER BY call.employee_id ASC, call.start_time ASC";
var newstringreplaced = string.replace(/FROM/gi, "0FROM");
var newstring = newstringreplaced.split("0");
console.log(newstring);
```

Comment: Cómo consigues que funcione sin indicar la palabra entre comillas en el método split()? Es que lo intento y me da error de sintaxis y si añado las comillas el método no se ejecuta correctamente

Comment: Fijate que mi palabra para separar es separo, es decir la añado pero en vez de con comillas, uso la barra y pongo la palabra entre parentesis.

Comment: Sí, si entiendo lo que me comentas. El problema es que yo intento aplicarlo y el método split me exige que el argumento sea un string y para eso hay que indicarlo entrecomillado, es decir, no sé por qué te acepta el /( )/

Comment: He editado la respuesa con otra posible solución, por si te sirve

Comment: Yo he añadido un ejemplo para que puedas comprobar qué quiero hacer exactamente.
Voy a intentar hacer lo que propones en tu nuevo ejemplo y te comento

Comment: Ya te he añadido tu ejemplo.
La explicación es que genero una nueva frase en la que remplazo el from, poniendo justo antes un 0 por ejemplo, o el separador que quieras que no esté repetido.
Y luego simplemente separo por ese separador.

Comment: Entiendo. Sabes de algún caracter en SQL que no cause confusión y que pueda usar para añadir en el replace para que, cuando haga el split, no corte la query por donde no debe? Como se trata de establecer un método automático, en principio puede entrar por parámetro cualquier tipo de query (No sé si me he explicado correctamente)

Comment: Este caracter no tiene ningun uso dentro de sql:  §

Comment: Perfecto. Creo que has dado en el clavo en todo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para el autor de la respuesta y @dancareli: Esta respuesta está en **JavaScript**, no en Java...

Comment: Llevas toda la razón @padaleiana Me ha funcionado por similitud, pero es cierto que la respuesta debería ser en Java y no JS

Comment: @dancareli me sorprende de hecho que tenga tantos votos positivos sin haber visto ese detalle :) El autor de la respuesta debe editar el código y convertir los snippets a bloques de código.

Comment: @ImSilent tal y como dice padaleiana deberías modificar la solución para que sea válida en Java

Comment: @ImSilent la pregunta indica "java" no "javascript", te sugerimos nuevamente revisar [answer], edita tu pregunta para que sea de ayuda a la comunidad.